# Dynamic Columns in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, dynamic-columns

I got a requirement to create dynamic reports where if a column is added in database that column should automatically need to be reflected in crystal reports.

I am wondering if dynamic column possible in crystal reports?

If yes.. How to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know by adding a column in db you can't get it on crystal reports via datatable but you can get it via stored procedure but you have to drag and drop the field. Go through this link hope it will help you

[Crystal report with Dynamic Column](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/uditsingh/CR1111022006055359AM/CR11.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response Umm-e-Habiba